# aws-load-balancer-controller error: cannot get the logs from *v1.Ingress: selector for *v1.Ingress not implemented

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks

I get this error when trying to get ALB logs:

```
root@b75651fde30e:/apps/tekton/deployment# kubectl logs -f ingress/tekton-dashboard-alb-dev
error: cannot get the logs from *v1.Ingress: selector for *v1.Ingress not implemented
```

The load balancer YAML:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: tekton-dashboard-alb-dev
  namespace: tekton-pipelines
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-name: tekton-dashboard-alb-dev
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: ip
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: HTTP
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/tags: "Cost=SwiftALK,VantaOnwer=foo@bar.com,VantaNonProd=true,VantaDescription=ALB Ingress for Tekton Dashboard,VantaContainsUserData=false,VantaUserDataStored=None"
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/security-groups: sg-034ca9846b81fd721
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: ""    
spec:
  defaultBackend:
    service:
      name: tekton-dashboard
      port:
        number: 9097
```

**Note:** `sg-034ca9846b81fd721` restricts access to our VPN CIDRs

Ingress is up as revealed from:

```
root@b75651fde30e:/apps/tekton/deployment# kubectl get ingress
NAME                       CLASS    HOSTS   ADDRESS                                                         PORTS   AGE
tekton-dashboard-alb-dev   <none>   *       tekton-dashboard-alb-dev-81361211.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com   80      103m
root@b75651fde30e:/apps/tekton/deployment# kubectl describe ingress/tekton-dashboard-alb-dev
Name:             tekton-dashboard-alb-dev
Namespace:        tekton-pipelines
Address:          tekton-dashboard-alb-dev-81361211.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com
Default backend:  tekton-dashboard:9097 (172.18.5.248:9097)
Rules:
  Host        Path  Backends
  ----        ----  --------
  *           *     tekton-dashboard:9097 (172.18.5.248:9097)
Annotations:  alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: HTTP
              alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-name: tekton-dashboard-alb-dev
              alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
              alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/security-groups: sg-034ca9846b81fd721
              alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/tags:
                Cost=SwiftALK,VantaOnwer=swiftalkdevteam@digite.com,VantaNonProd=true,VantaDescription=ALB Ingress for SwifTalk Web Microservices,VantaCon...
              alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: ip
              kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
Events:       <none>
```

Comment: Have you tried to get logs from ingress-controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The error you received means that the logs for your object are not implemented. It looks like you're trying to get logs from the wrong place.**

I am not able to reproduce your problem on AWS, but I tried to do it on GCP and the situation was very similar. You cannot get logs from `ingress/tekton-dashboard-alb-dev`, and this is normal bahaviour. If you want to get logs of your ALB, you have to find the appropriate pod and then extract the logs from it. Let me show you how I did it on GCP. The commands are the same, but the pod names will be different.

First I have executed:

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
```

Output:

```
NAMESPACE       NAME                                                     READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
ingress-nginx   ingress-nginx-controller-57cb5bf694-722ml                1/1     Running   0          18d

-----

and many other not related pods in other namespaces
```

You can find directly your pod with command:

```
kubectl get pods -n ingress-nginx
```

Output:

```
NAME                                        READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
ingress-nginx-controller-57cb5bf694-722ml   1/1     Running   0          18d
```

Now you can get logs from `ingress controller` by command:

```
kubectl logs -n ingress-nginx ingress-nginx-controller-57cb5bf694-722ml
```

in your situation:

```
kubectl logs -n <your namespace> <your ingress controller pod>
```

The output should be similar to this:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
NGINX Ingress controller
  Release:       v0.46.0
  Build:         6348dde672588d5495f70ec77257c230dc8da134
  Repository:    https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx
  nginx version: nginx/1.19.6

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

I0923 05:26:20.053561       8 flags.go:208] "Watching for Ingress" class="nginx"
W0923 05:26:20.053753       8 flags.go:213] Ingresses with an empty class will also be processed by this Ingress controller
W0923 05:26:20.054185       8 client_config.go:614] Neither --kubeconfig nor --master was specified.  Using the inClusterConfig.  This might not work.
I0923 05:26:20.054502       8 main.go:241] "Creating API client" host="https://10.16.0.1:443"
I0923 05:26:20.069482       8 main.go:285] "Running in Kubernetes cluster" major="1" minor="20+" git="v1.20.9-gke.1001" state="clean" commit="1fe18c314ed577f6047d2712a9d1c8e498e22381" platform="linux/amd64"
I0923 05:26:20.842645       8 main.go:105] "SSL fake certificate created" file="/etc/ingress-controller/ssl/default-fake-certificate.pem"
I0923 05:26:20.846132       8 main.go:115] "Enabling new Ingress features available since Kubernetes v1.18"
W0923 05:26:20.849470       8 main.go:127] No IngressClass resource with name nginx found. Only annotation will be used.
I0923 05:26:20.866252       8 ssl.go:532] "loading tls certificate" path="/usr/local/certificates/cert" key="/usr/local/certificates/key"
I0923 05:26:20.917594       8 nginx.go:254] "Starting NGINX Ingress controller"
I0923 05:26:20.942084       8 event.go:282] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"ConfigMap", Namespace:"ingress-nginx", Name:"ingress-nginx-controller", UID:"42dc476e-3c5c-4cc9-a6a4-266edecb2a4b", APIVersion:"v1", ResourceVersion:"5600", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'CREATE' ConfigMap ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx-controller
I0923 05:26:22.118459       8 nginx.go:296] "Starting NGINX process"
I0923 05:26:22.118657       8 leaderelection.go:243] attempting to acquire leader lease ingress-nginx/ingress-controller-leader-nginx...
I0923 05:26:22.119481       8 nginx.go:316] "Starting validation webhook" address=":8443" certPath="/usr/local/certificates/cert" keyPath="/usr/local/certificates/key"
I0923 05:26:22.120266       8 controller.go:146] "Configuration changes detected, backend reload required"
I0923 05:26:22.126350       8 status.go:84] "New leader elected" identity="ingress-nginx-controller-57cb5bf694-8c9tn"
I0923 05:26:22.214194       8 controller.go:163] "Backend successfully reloaded"
I0923 05:26:22.214838       8 controller.go:174] "Initial sync, sleeping for 1 second"
I0923 05:26:22.215234       8 event.go:282] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Pod", Namespace:"ingress-nginx", Name:"ingress-nginx-controller-57cb5bf694-722ml", UID:"b9672f3c-ecdf-473e-80f5-529bbc5bc4e5", APIVersion:"v1", ResourceVersion:"59016530", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'RELOAD' NGINX reload triggered due to a change in configuration
I0923 05:27:00.596169       8 leaderelection.go:253] successfully acquired lease ingress-nginx/ingress-controller-leader-nginx
I0923 05:27:00.596305       8 status.go:84] "New leader elected" identity="ingress-nginx-controller-57cb5bf694-722ml"
157.230.143.29 - - [23/Sep/2021:08:28:25 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 400 248 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0" 165 0.000 [] [] - - - - d47be1e37ea504aca93d59acc7d36a2b
157.230.143.29 - - [23/Sep/2021:08:28:26 +0000] "\x00\xFFK\x00\x00\x00\xE2\x00 \x00\x00\x00\x0E2O\xAAC\xE92g\xC2W'\x17+\x1D\xD9\xC1\xF3,kN\x17\x14" 400 150 "-" "-" 0 0.076 [] [] - - - - c497187f4945f8e9e7fa84d503198e85
157.230.143.29 - - [23/Sep/2021:08:28:26 +0000] "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00" 400 150 "-" "-" 0 0.138 [] [] - - - - 4067a2d34d0c1f2db7ffbfc143540c1a
167.71.216.70 - - [23/Sep/2021:12:02:23 +0000] "\x16\x03\x01\x01\xFC\x01\x00\x01\xF8\x03\x03\xDB\xBBo*K\xAE\x9A&\x8A\x9B)\x1B\xB8\xED3\xB7\xE16N\xEA\xFCS\x22\x14V\xF7}\xC8&ga\xDA\x00\x01<\xCC\x14\xCC\x13\xCC\x15\xC00\xC0,\xC0(\xC0$\xC0\x14\xC0" 400 150 "-" "-" 0 0.300 [] [] - - - - ff6908bb17b0da020331416773b928b5
167.71.216.70 - - [23/Sep/2021:12:02:23 +0000] "\x16\x03\x01\x01\xFC\x01\x00\x01\xF8\x03\x03a\xBF\xFB\xC1'\x03S\x83D\x5Cn$\xAB\xE1\xA6%\x93G-}\xD1C\xB2\xB0E\x8C\x8F\xA8q-\xF7$\x00\x01<\xCC\x14\xCC\x13\xCC\x15\xC00\xC0,\xC0(\xC0$\xC0\x14\xC0" 400 150 "-" "-" 0 0.307 [] [] - - - - fee3a478240e630e6983c60d1d510f52
66.240.205.34 - - [23/Sep/2021:12:04:11 +0000] "145.ll|'|'|SGFjS2VkX0Q0OTkwNjI3|'|'|WIN-JNAPIER0859|'|'|JNapier|'|'|19-02-01|'|'||'|'|Win 7 Professional SP1 x64|'|'|No|'|'|0.7d|'|'|..|'|'|AA==|'|'|112.inf|'|'|SGFjS2VkDQoxOTIuMTY4LjkyLjIyMjo1NTUyDQpEZXNrdG9wDQpjbGllbnRhLmV4ZQ0KRmFsc2UNCkZhbHNlDQpUcnVlDQpGYWxzZQ==12.act|'|'|AA==" 400 150 "-" "-" 0 0.086 [] [] - - - - 365d42d67e7378359b95c71a8d8ce983
147.182.148.98 - - [23/Sep/2021:12:04:17 +0000] "\x16\x03\x01\x01\xFC\x01\x00\x01\xF8\x03\x03\xABA\xF4\xD5\xB7\x95\x85[.v\xDB\xD1\x1B\x04\xE7\xB4\xB8\x92\x82\xEC\xCC\xDDr\xB7/\xBD\x93/\xD0f4\xB3\x00\x01<\xCC\x14\xCC\x13\xCC\x15\xC00\xC0,\xC0(\xC0$\xC0\x14\xC0" 400 150 "-" "-" 0 0.152 [] [] - - - - 858c2ad7535de95c84dd0899708a3801
164.90.203.66 - - [23/Sep/2021:12:08:19 +0000] "\x16\x03\x01\x01\xFC\x01\x00\x01\xF8\x03\x03\x93\x81+_\x95\xFA\xEAj\xA7\x80\x15 \x179\xD7\x92\xAE\xA9i+\x9D`\xA07:\xD2\x22\xB3\xC6\xF3\x22G\x00\x01<\xCC\x14\xCC\x13\xCC\x15\xC00\xC0,\xC0(\xC0$\xC0\x14\xC0" 400 150 "-" "-" 0 0.237 [] [] - - - - 799487dd8ec874532dcfa7dad1c02a27
164.90.203.66 - - [23/Sep/2021:12:08:20 +0000] "\x16\x03\x01\x01\xFC\x01\x00\x01\xF8\x03\x03\xB8\x22\xCB>1\xBEM\xD4\x92\x95\xEF\x1C0\xB5&\x1E[\xC5\xC8\x1E2\x07\x1C\x02\xA1<\xD2\xAA\x91F\x00\xC6\x00\x01<\xCC\x14\xCC\x13\xCC\x15\xC00\xC0,\xC0(\xC0$\xC0\x14\xC0" 400 150 "-" "-" 0 0.193 [] [] - - - - 4604513713d4b9fb5a7199b7980fa7f2
164.90.203.66 - - [23/Sep/2021:12:16:10 +0000] "\x16\x03\x01\x01\xFC\x01\x00\x01\xF8\x03\x03[\x16\x02\x94\x98\x17\xCA\xB5!\xC11@\x08\xD9\x89RE\x970\xC2\xDF\xFF\xEBh\xA0i\x9Ee%.\x07{\x00\x01<\xCC\x14\xCC\x13\xCC\x15\xC00\xC0,\xC0(\xC0$\xC0\x14\xC0" 400 150 "-" "-" 0 0.116 [] [] - - - - 23019f0886a1c30a78092753f6828e74
77.247.108.81 - - [23/Sep/2021:14:52:51 +0000] "GET /admin/config.php HTTP/1.1" 400 248 "-" "python-requests/2.26.0" 164 0.000 [] [] - - - - 04630dbf3d0ff4a4b7138dbc899080e5
209.141.48.211 - - [23/Sep/2021:16:17:46 +0000] "" 400 0 "-" "-" 0 0.057 [] [] - - - - 3c623b242909a99e18178ec10a814d7b
209.141.62.185 - - [23/Sep/2021:18:13:11 +0000] "GET /config/getuser?index=0 HTTP/1.1" 400 248 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:76.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/76.0" 353 0.000 [] [] - - - - 2640cf06912615a7600e814dc893884b
125.64.94.138 - - [23/Sep/2021:19:49:08 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 400 248 "-" "-" 18 0.000 [] [] - - - - b633636176888bc3b7f6230f691e0724
2021/09/23 19:49:20 [crit] 39#39: *424525 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:141CF06C:SSL routines:tls_parse_ctos_key_share:bad key share) while SSL handshaking, client: 125.64.94.138, server: 0.0.0.0:443
125.64.94.138 - - [23/Sep/2021:19:49:21 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 400 650 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4 240.111 Safari/537.36" 197 0.000 [] [] - - - - ede08c8fb12e8ebaf3adcbd2b7ea5fd5
125.64.94.138 - - [23/Sep/2021:19:49:22 +0000] "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1" 400 650 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4 240.111 Safari/537.36" 196 0.000 [] [] - - - - fae50b56a11600abc84078106ba4b008
125.64.94.138 - - [23/Sep/2021:19:49:22 +0000] "GET /.well-known/security.txt HTTP/1.1" 400 650 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4 240.111 Safari/537.36" 210 0.000 [] [] - - - - ad82bcac7d7d6cd9aa2d044d80bb719d
87.251.75.145 - - [23/Sep/2021:21:29:10 +0000] "\x03\x00\x00/*\xE0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00Cookie: mstshash=Administr" 400 150 "-" "-" 0 0.180 [] [] - - - - 8c2b62bcdf26ac1592202d0940fc30b8
167.71.102.181 - - [23/Sep/2021:21:54:58 +0000] "\x00\x0E8K\xA3\xAAe\xBCn\x14\x1B\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00" 400 150 "-" "-" 0 0.027 [] [] - - - - 65b8ee37a2c6bf8368843e4db3b90b2a
185.156.72.27 - - [23/Sep/2021:22:03:55 +0000] "\x03\x00\x00/*\xE0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00Cookie: mstshash=Administr" 400 150 "-" "-" 0 0.139 [] [] - - - - 92c6ad2d71b961bf7de4e345ff69da10
185.156.72.27 - - [23/Sep/2021:22:03:55 +0000] "\x03\x00\x00/*\xE0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00Cookie: mstshash=Administr" 400 150 "-" "-" 0 0.140 [] [] - - - - fe0424f8ecf9afc1d0154bbca2382d13
34.86.35.21 - - [23/Sep/2021:22:54:41 +0000] "\x16\x03\x01\x00\xE3\x01\x00\x00\xDF\x03\x03\x0F[\xA9\x18\x15\xD3@4\x7F\x7F\x98'\xA9(\x8F\xE7\xCCDd\xF9\xFF`\xE3\xCE\x9At\x05\x97\x05\xB1\xC3}\x00\x00h\xCC\x14\xCC\x13\xC0/\xC0+\xC00\xC0,\xC0\x11\xC0\x07\xC0'\xC0#\xC0\x13\xC0\x09\xC0(\xC0$\xC0\x14\xC0" 400 150 "-" "-" 0 2.039 [] [] - - - - c09d38bf2cd925dac4d9e5d5cb843ece
2021/09/24 02:41:15 [crit] 40#40: *627091 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:141CF06C:SSL routines:tls_parse_ctos_key_share:bad key share) while SSL handshaking, client: 184.105.247.252, server: 0.0.0.0:443
61.219.11.151 - - [24/Sep/2021:03:40:51 +0000] "dN\x93\xB9\xE6\xBCl\xB6\x92\x84:\xD7\x03\xF1N\xB9\xC5;\x90\xC2\xC6\xBA\xE1I-\x22\xDDs\xBA\x1FgC:\xB1\xA7\x80+\x00\x00\x00\x00%\xFDK:\xAAW.|J\xB2\xB5\xF5'\xA5l\xD3V(\xB7\x01%(CsK8B\xCE\x9A\xD0z\xC7\x13\xAD" 400 150 "-" "-" 0 0.203 [] [] - - - - 190d00221eefc869b5938ab6380f835a
46.101.155.106 - - [24/Sep/2021:04:56:37 +0000] "HEAD / HTTP/1.0" 400 0 "-" "-" 17 0.000 [] [] - - - - e8c108201c37d7457e4578cf68feacf8
46.101.155.106 - - [24/Sep/2021:04:56:38 +0000] "GET /system_api.php HTTP/1.1" 400 650 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36" 255 0.000 [] [] - - - - b3032f9a9b3f4f367bdee6692daeb05c
46.101.155.106 - - [24/Sep/2021:04:56:39 +0000] "GET /c/version.js HTTP/1.1" 400 650 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36" 253 0.000 [] [] - - - - 9104ab72a0232caf6ff98da57d325144
46.101.155.106 - - [24/Sep/2021:04:56:40 +0000] "GET /streaming/clients_live.php HTTP/1.1" 400 650 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36" 267 0.000 [] [] - - - - 341cbb6cf424b348bf8b788f79373b8d
46.101.155.106 - - [24/Sep/2021:04:56:41 +0000] "GET /stalker_portal/c/version.js HTTP/1.1" 400 650 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36" 268 0.000 [] [] - - - - 9954fd805fa092595057dbf83511bd92
46.101.155.106 - - [24/Sep/2021:04:56:42 +0000] "GET /stream/live.php HTTP/1.1" 400 248 "-" "AlexaMediaPlayer/2.1.4676.0 (Linux;Android 5.1.1) ExoPlayerLib/1.5.9" 209 0.000 [] [] - - - - 3c9409419c1ec59dfc08c10cc3eb6eef
```

Answer (score -1):

It is as the message says: there is no such thing as "logs" for an `Ingress` resource. Specifically, what it is telling you is that running `kubectl -n tekton-pipelines get pods -l $(kubectl -n tekton-pipelines get -o jsonpath={.metadata.labels} ingress/tekton-dashboard-alb-dev)` correctly produced no Pods from which one could gather logs

Perhaps you actually wanted the logs for the Pods behind `service/tekton-dashboard` but asking for the logs of an `Ingress` is nonsense